# ¿Como puedo remover este texto que aparece en algunos articulos de mi wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Tengo muchos artículos en un sitio de wordpress y en algunos se cuela texto de la parte del titulo o del contenido a la parte de arriba, no me lo explico y quisiera saber de que manera puedo limpiar éstos artículos de antemano gracias.

[image: articulo de wordpress con texto sin etiqueta]

Comment: Sinceramente no se logra ver nada. Al menos para mi es imposible ver esas letras :( ¿Estas trabajando con código PHP o todo de manera visual?

Comment: Eso debe estar en alguna parte de tu tema, plantilla o sale por pantalla desde alguna función, shortcode o hook de Wordpress. Puede ser también contenido de algún plugin... Así nada más poco podemos decirte. Revisa el código fuente de la página, allí encontrarás quizá información más precisa sobre el origen de ese contenido.

Comment: Seguramente estás copiando html y está mal anidado. Si copias un texto que por ejemplo cierra una etiqueta que no está abierta previamente puede desarmarse tu estructura visual, para eso hay que revisar que el contenido esté limpio de etiquetas externas. Y también como dicen, revisar que el origen no sea `functions.php` de tu plantilla o algo parecido.

Comment: Edgar Gc, todo visual, lo siento por la combinación de colores

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano, revisare.

Comment: Gracias Rvera, ¿donde encuentro el functions.php? jejeje